# creating hyperlink dynamically

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to create a hyperlink from code-behind, but it is not creating it where i want it to be.

if i look at my souce code is creating somewhere else and from .aspx page it seems like everything is in place where it needs to be.

.aspx

```
<div class="AZ">
    <ol class="AZlist">   
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="AToZ"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
    </ol>
</div>
```

.codebehind

```
HyperLink links = new HyperLink();
links.Text =  "<li>" + CheckMe.ToString() + "</li>";
links.NavigateUrl = "<a href='#'" + CheckMe.ToString() + ">";
ph.Controls.Add(links);
```

source code:

....
....
...

```
   <div class="AZ">
    <ol class="AZlist">
           // I WANT HYPERLINK HERE....!!!!!!!!!!!
    </ol>
    <br />
</div>
 </li>
```

but its creating outside the div area here

`<a href="#A"><li>A</li></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you should put those tags in the .text and .navigateurl properties. just put the link and the text in them. Put the `<li>` tags around the placeholder.

Comment: `<li>` tags around the placeholder? will you show what you mean by that?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done asp.net webforms, but I found this on the internet. I think this is what you need. `HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("ol");

HtmlGenericControl b = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

b.InnerHtml = "<a href='/'>Home</a>;

a.Controls.Add(b); //similarly you can add more li controls to ul

AToZ.Controls.Add(a);` And delete the <ol> tags, because if you dont have any links to display, you wont need them (it gets generated dynamically in this piece of code)

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the way you're doing it here.  Try making your ol tag runat="server" and give it an id.  Then create a new ListItem control, add the hyperlink control, and add the ListItem to the ol.

Something like this in the codebehind:

```
dim anLi = new ListItem([can't remember exact parameters])
dim aHyperlink = new Hyperlink([whatever to initialize])
anLi.addControl(aHyperlink)
theOl.controls.add(anLi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an asp:repeater instead.

You could then put all your Mark up in the aspx template making use of header / detail / footer templating.  Next just get the text and URL values into a bindable format in the code behind and data bind.

Saves doing markup in code behind and the need to dynamically insert controls which can cause headaches on post backs.